# How do I pre-deform text for correct spherical wrapping?

Tags: opengl, blender, unity3d

Imagine taking a mercator map of the Earth, then add numbers on each line of latitude and longitude.  When you wrap that around a sphere the numbers will be deformed.

How can I pre-deform the numbers so that when wrapped around the sphere they will appear correct (un-deformed)?

Currently I am using Blender and modelling the text in 3D on the sphere, then joining the text with the sphere and unwrapping the resulting object.  That worked, but I have to fight with blender for a week each time to get a mercator projection of my sphere (something blender really really doesn't want to do, especially when you add objects to the sphere).

Is there a better way?